# What does "lavor" mean when talking about land?

Tags: definiciones

I've seen this on a website selling land:

> 120 HECTAREAS DE **LAVOR** 60 DE PASTOS Y RESTO DEHEZA

(It is possible this may be Andaluz - a word used locally in Andalusia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a doubt it is a misspelling of *labor*.  Within this context, *labor* is related to this definition from the DRAE:

> *labor* **4.** *f.* Labranza, en especial la de las tierras que se siembran. *Apl.* a las demás operaciones agrícolas, *u. m. en pl.*

In other words, it's farmland/land for agriculture that's already been divided into *pasto* and *dehesa* (note the *s* is the correct spelling).  Of course, my understanding is that *pasto* is a type of *dehesa* so I'm not totally sure the distinction he's making but I'm not an agriculture guy either.

Comment: Thanks - that's a well reasoned answer that makes sense. My understanding was that pasto is pasture whereas dehesa is land without anything growing or constructed on it.

Comment: @Playability Remember than labor comes from Latin _laborare_ that was the verb to say _work_, that in Spanish was substituted by _trabajar_ meanwhile _laborar_ still means to work but has a more formal meaning, bun in the other hand it evoluted and gave place to many works about work but in agriculture.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be something that happens often in the Spanish of Spain, a word of Catalan is slipped into the phrase: *llavor* in Catalan means *semilla* in Spanish, *seed* in English.